# fail2ban is running but no fail2ban.log log file exists for it

Tags: logs, fail2ban

I've set up fail2ban on a centos VPS used for a few mail accounts among other things and want to check that everything is running smoothly. According to `fail2ban-client status` everything is running as expected on dovecot, exim, and ssh, but there's no log file in the expected place (`/var/log/fail2ban.log`), and `find / -name fail2ban.log` finds nothing.

`fail2ban-client get loglevel` returns `Current logging level is 'INFO'`, and `fail2ban-client get logtarget` returns `Current logging target is:- SYSLOG`. Based on this, it should be logging in the default location, which all the docs and guides I've found say is `/var/log/fail2ban.log`, but no log file is there.

There have been many of the usual probes on dovecot since setting fail2ban up including many from repeat IPs, so it's not like fail2ban has had nothing to do.

How can I investigate why fail2ban has not got any log file and appears to be failing to log? Searches uncovered a few people posting about similar problems on a few forums but no solutions I could see.

Comment: The location of the log depends on your `syslog` implementation and configuration.  Did you look in `/var/log/messages` which is now the most common place.  Note that troubleshooting `fail2ban` is not an easy task unless you make a good effort in understanding how it works.

Comment: Which CentOS version do you use? Does it include `systemd`?

Comment: I don't have a `/var/log/messages` directory, and a system-wide `find` didn't find it, so I'm pretty sure it's not being created, rather than I'm looking in the wrong place. `rpm --query centos-release` gives `centos-release-6-7.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64`, no systemd

Comment: `/var/log/messages` is a file, not a directory. can you paste the contents of `/var/log` ?

Comment: @schaiba Oops, yes I do have that file and it does contain fail2ban logging messages. Looks like I was simply looking at out-of-date docs and discussions that all talked about a standalone fail2ban.log file, /var/log/messages is the answer

Comment: @JuliePelletier yes actually the fail2ban logs are present in the `/var/log/messages` file, looks like I was reading out of date docs. Put that as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The location of the log depends on your `syslog` implementation and configuration.

`/var/log/messages` is the most common place.

Note that troubleshooting fail2ban is not an easy task unless you make a good effort in understanding how it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your Fail2ban to write logs to: `/var/log/fail2ban.log`

1. Open the `/etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf` file
2. Change the line: `logtarget = SYSLOG` to `logtarget = /var/log/fail2ban.log`
3. `restart fail2ban service`

Fail2ban will start writing logs to the `/var/log/fail2ban.log` file.